# Maintaining a billion of key:value pairs in a file

Tags: java, algorithm

With Java, how to store around a billion of key-value pairs in a file, with a possibility of dynamically updating and querying the values whenever necessary?

Comment: I'm sure you considered using a database?

Comment: What type of File it will be? How you will  you open it  if needed? Will any 1 billion record file will open ?  may be in one week? why not using  DB? Anywaygood luck buddy. Try and and come again if anything blocks you. :)

Comment: try Redis http://code.google.com/p/redis/

Comment: I cant use database, though I will suggest. I am using text file.
This is the requirement, I hardly can change..

Comment: Could you consider having many files? instead of one big file, distribute values into many files(probably in many directories?)

Comment: There is also http://code.google.com/p/disk-backed-map/

Comment: why is there a requirement to use such a poor design?

Comment: Yea, once upon a time every programmer makes poor design and cooks dumb algorithms. So did I..
Please note, it was asked 2 years ago..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If for some reason a database is out of the question, then you need to answer the following question about your problem:

What is the mix of the following operations?

- Insert
- Read
- Modify
- Delete
- Search

Once you have a good guess at the ratio of these operations, try selecting the appropriate data structure for use in your file.  I'd recommend starting with this book as a good catalog of options:

[http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Algorithms-Second-Thomas-Cormen/dp/0262032937](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262032937)

You'll want to select a data structure with the best average and worst case runtimes for your most common operations.

Good Luck

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I will consider this.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but this is a case for log files.  You do not want to be copying a billion records over every time you do a delete.  This can be solved by logging all "transactions" or updates to a new and separate file.  These files should be broken up into reasonable sizes.

To read a tuple, you start at the newest log file until you find your key, then stop.  To update or insert you just add a new record into the most recent log file.  A delete is still a log entry.

A batch coalesce process needs to be run periodically which will scan each log file and write out another master.  As it is read, each NEW key gets written to the new master and duplicate (old) keys are skipped until you make it all the way through.  If you encounter a delete record, mark it in a separate delete list skip the record and ignore subsequent records with that key.

That made it sound simple, but remember you may want to block/chunk your file as you will likely scan said log files in reverse, or you will at least `seek()` to the max size and write in reverse instead of read.

I have done this exact thing with billions of lines of data.  You're just re-inventing sequential access databases.

Comment: Doesn't the question state "a file"? Note: if it is 'a file', the problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: @CMR, you mean to reference that he's looking for a SINGLE file or at least a single filesystem file representation?  If so, then we've got only 3 options 1) re-write 1b records each XA, 2) batch XAs for sequential change but still re-write and 3) log to the data file.

Comment: that is my guess. You are very right in saying that Ringo is reinventing the wheel. Others have suggested lightweight dbs, memory-mapped files, etc.,

Answer (score 0):

Can you use a database? Managing such a large file would be a pain.

Edit: if the file requirement is mostly to avoid machine communication failures, downtime and similar situations, maybe you could use an embedded database. This way you would be freed from the large file manipulation problems and still use all the advantages a database can give you. I already used  [Apache Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/) as an embedded database with wonderful results. [Java DB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javadb/overview/index.html) is Oracle supported and based on Derby.

Comment: Thats not in my requirement :( I hardly can change anything

Comment: Edited, additional suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You leave out a lot of details, but...

Are the keys static?  What about the values?  Are they fixed size?  Why not use a database?

If you don't want to use a database then use a memory mapped file.

Comment: Keys are static, but on the fly I have to change values if needed